# How can I recover data from a month that I havent pay?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

How can I recover data from a month that I haven't paid for? My due date has past and I forgot to update the attached credit card. I have a new one but I want to recover data that Firebase has not captured.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're asking about Analytics data, but please edit your question to clarify.

Analytics data is only streamed from Firebase to BigQuery while the integration is active. There is no way to get historical data from Analytics to BigQuery beyond that, so there's no way for you to get the data from the month that your integration was disabled due to a lagged payment status.